# R: How to create a barplot from a multi-column frequency data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, data-analysis

Assume I have a dataset as follows,

```
ID     Class
a      Class_1
a      Class_1
b      Class_1
b      Class_1
b      Class_1

c      Class_2
c      Class_2
c      Class_2
d      Class_2
d      Class_2
d      Class_2

e      Class_3
f      Class_3
```

I want to show, there are 
2 Students in Class_1,
2 Students in Class_2 and 
2 Students in Class_3 on a **barchart** using **ggplot()**

I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: `dput` of your dataset would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c(letters[c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6)]), 
            Class = c(rep("Class_1", 5), rep("Class_2", 6), "Class_3", "Class_3"))
```

if you want to show the information of the factor's number

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes (x = Class, fill = ID) ) + geom_bar(position="fill")
plot(p)    # check the number of breaks and use it as length
p + scale_y_continuous(label=seq(0, 2, length=5))
# Hoom, something strange ?
```

needn't

```
ggplot(d[! duplicated(d),], aes (x = Class, fill = ID) ) + geom_bar()
```

[image: plot]
[image: plot]

Comment: My apology! My question was wrong. Would you want to look at the updated question again?

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem.

ggplot(d[! duplicated(d),], aes (x = Class, fill = ID) ) + geom_bar()
This one works fine. However, it worked when I had two columns in the new data set. I guess, duplicator was giving different result for more than two columns.

Comment: If there're other columns,  ggplot(d[ ! duplicated( d[ , c(1, 2) ] ), ], aes (x = Class, fill = ID) ) + geom_bar().  You can decide the key col of duplicated().

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you provide above is in a data frame called `dat`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Class)) + geom_bar()
```

Should work. The default for `geom_bar` is to obtain frequencies.

Comment: Hi David, I have made a mistake in my original post, my apology. Now, I have corrected it, students should be unique students in each class. Hope it is clear now?